# ConstraintLayout not dynamically changing Height with Wrap_Content inside RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-view, android-constraintlayout

I have a `StaggeredLayout` `RecyclerView` that is filled with different cards using `CardView`, inside those cards there is normally a `ConstraintLayout` with all the fields empty. Everything has `wrap_content` as height.

My problem is that it seems the CardView height is being calculated before any data is filled and not updated afterwards. I have already tried directly invalidating, setting `measureAllChildren` to true, using `requestLayout` on the `itemView` and making so that the bottom items have a constraint to the bottom of the parent but the problem perseveres.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="@dimen/home_card_half_min_gutter">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:padding="@dimen/content_spacing">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_icon"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/content_spacing"
        android:contentDescription="@string/icon"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_airplanemode_inactive_accent_dark_24dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.35" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_item_1_label"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
        tools:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_item_1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/content_half_spacing"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/tv_item_1_label"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_item_1_label"
        tools:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_item_2_label"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline5"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
        tools:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_item_2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/content_half_spacing"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/tv_item_2_label"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_item_2_label"
        tools:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_item_3_label"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/content_spacing"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/tv_item_1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_item_1"
        tools:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_item_3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/content_half_spacing"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/tv_item_3_label"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_item_3_label"
        tools:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_item_4_label"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/content_spacing"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/tv_item_2"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_item_2"
        tools:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_item_4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/content_half_spacing"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/tv_item_4_label"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_item_4_label"
        tools:text="TextView" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The fields are filled inside the method `onBindViewHolder` on the adapter as follows:

```
DataExample example = mItems.get(position);
Card4ViewHolder vhCon = (Card4ViewHolder) holder;

vhCon.mIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_data);

vhCon.mItem1Label.setText(R.string.A_label);
vhCon.mItem1.setText(example.getA());

vhCon.mItem2Label.setText(R.string.B_label);
vhCon.mItem2.setText(example.getB());

vhCon.mItem3Label.setText(R.string.C_label);
vhCon.mItem3.setText(example.getC());

vhCon.mItem4Label.setText(R.string.D_label);
vhCon.mItem4.setText(example.getD());
```

The `RecyclerView` is initialized as follows:

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = res.getDisplayMetrics();
float pixelWidth =  displayMetrics.widthPixels;
int noOfColumns = (int) (pixelWidth / res.getDimension(R.dimen.home_card_min_width));
mLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(noOfColumns,
        StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
mLayoutManager.setGapStrategy(StaggeredGridLayoutManager
        .GAP_HANDLING_MOVE_ITEMS_BETWEEN_SPANS);
mHomeCardAdapter = new HomeCardAdapter(activity);
mCardsRecyclerView.setAdapter(mHomeCardAdapter);
mCardsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

and the layout which it is inside of is a fragment as defined here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/home_rv_dashboard_cards"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</ScrollView>
```

Scrolling and so on works without a problem, the size of the `RecyclerView` is also updated `on the fly`.

EDIT: I already tried changing the `StaggeredLayout` to a `LinearLayoutManager` and even removing the `CardView` altogether. After these tests I seemed to confirm that the problem is in the `ConstraintLayout` itself.

Comment: Could you post your Recyclerview?

Comment: I edited the original post adding more information.

Comment: Isn't the whole purpose of `ConstraintLayout` to avoid nesting. Now if you wrap it inside `CardView` vis `FrameLayout` that's again nesting and useless overdraw.

Comment: The purpose of the `ConstraingLayout` is to **minimize** nesting, which in some cases may still be the best option. Here I wanted a card layout with backward compatible shadows, which is what `CardView` does.(and the problem I had came from the `ConstraintLayout` itself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching for quite some time, I realized that the problem was a big oversight of my part.

On the `ImageView` we see that the height is defined by the Constraints, and the constraint bottom is the guideline:

```
<ImageView
    ...
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    ...
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
    ... />
```

The guideline itself is has a percentage position based on the final height of the card.

```
<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.35" />
```

So what I got here was a case of mutual dependencies, the height of the whole card is defined by the items inside and the height of the Image is percentage of that height. What I think happens is that the height of the card is looked up based on the combined heights of what is inside(0dp for the image) and then the image is scaled and placed moving everything down with it.

TLDR: I oversaw a mutual dependency and setting the size of the image veforehand fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this could help you:
Change:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/home_rv_dashboard_cards"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</ScrollView>
```

to

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/home_rv_dashboard_cards"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"/>
```

Then remove this lines from your code (where you initialize recyclerview):

```
mLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(noOfColumns,
        StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
mLayoutManager.setGapStrategy(StaggeredGridLayoutManager
        .GAP_HANDLING_MOVE_ITEMS_BETWEEN_SPANS);
mCardsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

Comment: This fundamentally changes what I am trying to achieve. In the project I am working we need a non linear card layout, with different card sizes in a grid. But even making the changes suggested, the `wrap_content` still doesn't work.
The problem is with the `CardView` I think, because even using the `LinearLayoutManager` it persists.

Comment: Maybe adding image of what you get and what you want to achieve could be more of help. I would be more helpful that way ;)

Comment: I just posted an answer that fixed my problem. It was a mutual dependency, the image size was based on the view size and the view size on its contents. But thanks for your help, I discarded the CardView and RecyclerView based on your comment and some experimentation.